# Is gradle tools:selector for permissions works ever?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, permissions, android-manifest

I have a project in Android Studio with two modules, say it **Module1** and **Module2** with dinamic generation a lot of product flavors using configuration files. **Module2** is library linked to **Module1**. Also I have compiled **third-party library** (AltBeacons). **3rd-party lib** declares permissions for **BLUETOOTH** and **BLUETOOTH_ADMIN**, but I d't want to use features that need these permissions in every flavor (only for one exactly) and can't move out **lib** from depenencies because of my Application inheritor uses it and appear as parent for another class that used in all flavors. So, I can fetch permissions from configuration files and declare them in **Module2** manifest to merge later, but **3rd party library** provides its permissions in all cases. I tried merge attributes but no luck. Here's my main manifest part where I tried to resolve the problem:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    tools:node="remove"
    tools:selector="org.altbeacon.beacon" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    tools:node="remove"
    tools:selector="org.altbeacon.beacon" />
```

, where 'org.altbeacon.beacon' is **3-rd party** package.
Resulting manifest includes permissions in all cases. If remove 'tools:selector' declaration, then specified permissions not came from all libs, but I need they if fetched from my **Module2**. Please, help me!

Comment: PS: Manifest merges for Module1 - its a main project module.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this? I'm having the same issue.